# Validate parameters in SSIS 2008

Tags: ssis

I'm struggling to find an easy and simple way to validate the parameters of my SSIS package.
I feel this is the basic feature any tool allowing parameters should provide : checking those values are in a specific "allowed" range and not allowing a user to pass any value (or forget to provide a mandatory value).
Especially in SSIS where the variables values can be replaced easily (throuh parameters when calling or XML configuration files).

I found some "solutions" involving VB6 scripting or constraints on tasks. But all of this feels like workarounds.

What is the best practice for checking the variables/parameters values before executing the main SSIS package tasks ?

Example:  my package can process data for 3 entities of my company : 'NHY', 'JIO', 'NTL' and 2 modes 'Q' and 'M'. The "caller" specifies which data he wants to process by passing the value when calling the SSIS package. But if the user specifies an entity that doesn't exist or a mode not supported, I want the package to fail immediately.

Example of command line that should fail BEFORE doing anything:

> /FILE "Path\To\File\MyPackage.dtsx" /CHECKPOINTING OFF  /REPORTING EWCDI  /SET EntityCode;ZZZZZ /SET ProcessMode;Z

Comment: What kind of parameters are you talking about?  Give some examples.

Comment: Then doesn't the Parameter Validation Dialog do this for you? (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213132.aspx)

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention I'm using SSIS 2008

Comment: I'm pretty sure that a task to check these early in the control flow is about all that you can do once it gets to the DTEXEC command line.  (I generally write a custom CMD file to launch my packages that checks such parameters ahead of time)

Comment: How does 'The caller specifies which data he wants to process by passing the value when calling the SSIS package' - He doesn't build his own command line does he? Given that SSIS is not meant to be interactive with user (i.e. error sources) then you'll either need to put validation in the package or in whatever you'er using to build the command line. Normal defensive programming means you should avoid or error-handle 'magic codes' like this.

Comment: The "user" is a planned task, but I work in a bank (I've never seen so many manual "fixes" than in a bank...) and everyday we need to perform manual tasks or (re)launch some process manually. So the package might be called manually, I just want to avoid any input mistakes or hard-to-understand failures because of incorrect input parameter.
I'm a .net "desktop" developer and learned that any external input should be validated and to not trust parameters. This is what I'm trying to do here.
Your comments make me think this might not be the "right" way for SSIS development :).

Comment: Downvote ? This is a real world question and a real world problem... What I'm trying to do might not be the right way, but I don't feel it is not a legitimate question.

Comment: I hear what you are saying... I've created a front end that allows the users to trigger a package and allows them to specify values for parameters if configured. There's validation on the front-end, but I'd still like to do some validation in the package - even if it's as simple as checking for the existence of a value in the parameter. What it looks like it's going to come down to is passing the parameters into an _Execute SQL Task_ and validating there and branching the logic in the package based on the return result.